# How can I fix my webpage's header in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to have a fixed header on my webpage, i.e. it should always remain visible, even when scrolling. Note that my page is fixed width (800px) and horizontally centered on the screen.

**What I've tried:**

```
<header class="noselect" style="position:fixed; top:0px; height:70px; 
                                background-color:#222D2D; margin:auto;">
  <p>
    <!-- header stuff goes here -->
  </p>
</header>
<div class="separator clearfloat" style="position:fixed; top:71px; height:1px;">
</div>
```

The separator is a horizontal line which should go all the width of the screen, see the footer.

Problems with this:
 1. using the `position:fixed` also places it at left=0, instead of centered.
 2. the separator doesn't show.

I can make the separator visible by placing it inside the header, but then the width is limited to 800px:

```
<header class="noselect" style="position:fixed; top:0px; height:70px; 
                                background-color:#222D2D; margin:auto;">
  <p>
    <!-- header stuff goes here -->
  </p>
  <div class="separator clearfloat"></div>
</header>
```

The testpage is [here](http://stevenvanhulle.net/tx140826a.php).
How do I fix this?

Comment: Creating a jsfiddle is preferable (many of us do not click on links to unknown domains..)

Comment: @thebjorn - I'll see what I can do, thanks for the tip. But what do you mean "many of us do not click on links to unknown domains". Isn't the internet full of "unknown domains"?

Comment: Yes, it sure is.  I don't go clicking willy-nilly on all of them though.. If I knew you I wouldn't have a problem clicking on a link you posted, but otherwise I must really want to see the "kittens" to click on a link posted by a random person on the internet (no offense :-) -- it's just not worth the risk.  My attitude might be colored by the fact that I'm usually the person who has to clean up after someone just wanted to see the "cute kitten" on a work computer..

Comment: @thebjorn I think that idea kinda falls short though. I mean, you can put pretty much anything in a jsfiddle. For example you can iframe a pornsite all up in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would position parent element as fixed and center `header` with `margin: 0 auto;`

<kbd>[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/yrk666g4/)</kbd>

Html:

```
<div id="top">
    <header>Header</header>
</div>

<main>
    <!-- Lots of content here. -->
</main>
```

Css:

```
#top { 
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; top: 0px; right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    /* The below styling is here for illustrative purpose only. */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#top header, 
main {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#top header {
    height: 100px;
    /* Border styling is here for illustrative purpose only. */
    border-left: 1px dashed #c1c1c1;
    border-right: 1px dashed #c1c1c1;
}

main { margin-top: 100px; /* Should be the same as '#top header' height. */ }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, and I like the opacity touch. Seems I actually have to add the `left:0; right:0` to make it work, although I don't understand the `right` parameter. `z-index` doesn't seem necessary. Again, thanks a bunch.

Comment: @stevenvh Well, using `left: 0;`  and `right: 0;` together basically stretches the element to full width. `z-index: 1;` is pretty much just my own habit to always include `z-index` if I set a `position`. There is a reason though. Here are two jsfiddle examples: [**Example 1:** No z-index](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/yrk666g4/1/) -- [**Example 2:** Z-index](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/yrk666g4/3/). Now this behavior can be easily countered, but I find it easier to just always include a z-index so I'll know where everything should be.

Comment: Also, if you don't use z-index and you move `.example` above `#top` ..`#top` will it stack above it. [**Example 3:** No z-index and different stacking order](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/yrk666g4/5/). While I can't for the life of me explain this in simple terms.. the idea is that all of this could have been prevented, if in the beginning I had set `z-index` to every element that is positioned.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I guess it's indeed a good habit to use z-index with position.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a working solution.

In `<header>` wrap all the content (except separating line) with a `<div>`.
To that `<div>` you should add

```
overflow: hidden; //optional clearfix
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

And also you should add `width: 100%;` to `<header>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just make your header the full width of the page and make that position: fixed;
Then wrap your header content in a div tag and set that to width: 800px; margin: auto;
This makes your header stay on a fixed position on top of your page.
And uses the div to set your menu/header data in the middle of the page.